# Java: Min and Max Date range

Tags: java, date

I'm grabbing some data from a database that has a stored date value, and I'm letting the user pick date ranges they would like to view data for. All my code for getting these date ranges works except for the method to get the date range covering all time, which would be a start value of the earliest possible data Java handles, to the end value of the max possible date.

Is there something wrong with my code, because I can't see a problem:

```
public static DateRange getAllTime() {
        /**
         * Get earliest possible
         */
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(
                c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.YEAR), 
                c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH), 
                c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 
                c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR), 
                c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE), 
                c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND)
            );

        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        Date start = c.getTime();

        /**
         * Get latest possible date
         */
        c.set(
                c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.YEAR), 
                c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH), 
                c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 
                c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.HOUR), 
                c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MINUTE), 
                c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.SECOND)
            );

        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        Date end = c.getTime();

        DateRange range = new DateRange();
        range.Start = start;
        range.End = end;

        return range;
    }
```

Comment: What does your method return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why make life so complicated? If you don't have a start date, don't query for a start date. If you don't have an end date, don't query for an end date. And if you have neither, don't query for dates at all.

Comment: Haha yeah, that's what I ended up doing. This was a special case, and since every other case had some start/end I just used one method. Ended up writing a method to cover this case and wrote a query that didn't check the date.

That said, it bugs me to not know and I'd really like to know why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 18):

Why not use

1. new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE) (in YEAR 292269055 BC)
2. new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE) (in YEAR 292278994 AD)?

Since froginvasion challenged the answer, I thought I'd double check

```
    long day=1000*60*60*24;
    System.out.println(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE-day));
    System.out.println(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));
    System.out.println(new Date(0));
    System.out.println(new Date(-day));
    System.out.println(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
    System.out.println(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE+day));
```

gave me

```
Sat Aug 16 07:12:55 GMT 292278994
Sun Aug 17 07:12:55 GMT 292278994
Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970
Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT 1969
Sun Dec 02 16:47:04 GMT 292269055
Mon Dec 03 16:47:04 GMT 292269055
```

I think it is right.  I assume the AD/BC are just being suppressed.  The suggestion to use new Date(0) as the minimum is clearly wrong because new Date(-day) is clearly smaller.

Comment: `new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)` wont work, test it. It does not actually do something you'd expect. If you want to use this, use `new Date(0)`which is in 1st of january 1970.

Comment: @froginvasion I think the answer is correct and that the string does not contain the BC/AD.  I do not think new Date(0) will give you the minimum date value.

Answer (score 0):

That code works me, maybe you're not expecting the values it returns?

Start: Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 1
End: Wed Apr 17 21:34:08 PST 292269054

(It would be easier to help if you included the stack trace)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect may get an overflow by setting the year and then setting maximum values for all the other fields separately.  That would make your end time somewhere around your start time and cause all records to be rejected.  You might try just printing out the calendar times to see what's happening.

As seanizer points out, you're really making this more complicated than it should be - the correct way to deal with this is to leave the date clause off entirely in the query.  That may be difficult sometimes because the sql statement isn't generated dynamically.  But note that even if you can't modify the sql at run time, the condition (in Oracle)

```
start_date >= nvl(?, start_date)
```

will always be satisfied if the supplied value is null and start_date is populated.

Answer (score 0):

### Min and max supported by your database?

You may actually need the minimum and maximum value supported by your database rather than the minimum and maximum supported by Java. Some databases have `datetime` types that only support, say years 0001 through 9999. I haven’t tried nor studied the documentation, but I might suspect that either your JDBC driver or your query may fail if you pass dates outside the interval supported by the database.

For example the MariaDB documentation says:

> MariaDB stores values that use the `DATETIME` data type in a format
> that supports values between `1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000` and
> `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999`.

It’s not very nice to have Java code that depends on a specific brand of database engine (DBMS), though. If you nevertheless need to, just hardcode the values:

```
public static final LocalDateTime MIN_DATABASE_DATETIME
        = LocalDateTime.of(1000, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0);
public static final LocalDateTime MAX_DATABASE_DATETIME
        = LocalDateTime.of(9999, Month.DECEMBER, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999_999_000);
```

I am using and recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Min and max supported by Java?

The minimum and maximum values supported by Java are built in as constants. java.time supports a wider range than the old-fashioned `Date` class did. Let’s see what the minimum and maximum are:

```
    System.out.println("Min Java LocalDateTime: " + LocalDateTime.MIN);
    System.out.println("Max Java LocalDateTime: " + LocalDateTime.MAX);
```

Output:

> ```
> Min Java LocalDateTime: -999999999-01-01T00:00
> Max Java LocalDateTime: +999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999
> ```

### What went wrong in your code?

> Is there something wrong with my code, because I can't see a problem:

You are correct, while your code gives a minimum value that you may be able to use as minimum, the max value that it gives is about as far off as can be. When I ran it just now, I got:

> Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 1 - Wed Apr 17 21:34:08 CST 292269054

`Calendar` and `Date` *did* support dates before the common era (“before Christ”), so giving year 1 as minimum is not correct. This happens because you have not changed the era of your `Calendar`, so it remains in CE (“AD”). The `YEAR` field number denotes year of era, so the minimum value is 1.

The maximum value I got *looks like* it lies 9940 years before the maximum possible `Date` but probably still way above any date actually present in your data. This is not so! The value you got is in year 292269054 *before the common era* (“before Christ“) and just 4 and a half months after the minimum value of a `Date`, pretty much the opposite of what you had tried to find. This is probably due to undetected arithmetic overflow in the computation. I suppose that  `Calendar` never meant to guard against overflow and underflow.

`getActualMinimum()` and `getActualMaximum()` give you the min and max values possible *given the actual value* of the `Calendar`. So `c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH)` would give you 28 in February in a non-leap year and 31 in July. This is not what you wanted. Using `Calendar.HOUR` is a further bug since `HOUR` denotes the hour within AM or PM from 0 through 11.

The actual min and max values of `Date` and `Calendar` do not fall on midnight nor at New Year, but your code will try to find values at or very close to midnight in the night of New Year, which is the flaw by your technique. Trying to find December 31 in the year where the maximum value fell in August probably accounts for the overflow I mentioned. The 4 and half months you overflowed by roughly agrees with the 4 and a half months above the minimum value where we ended up.

### Links

- [`DATETIME` in the MariaDB knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datetime/)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.